# Comparing the Columns of a Format-Table Output in Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I've been scratching my head over this one for a while now.

I am compiling a script to create a new Office365 user account in Powershell.  I would like to add a check for the amount of licenses that a tennant has and prompt the admin to go to the web portal to add more licenses if the tennant does not have a spare license

I would like to select EXCHANGESTANDARD and compare the ActiveUnits to the ConsumedUnits to ensure that there are more ActiveUnits than ConsumedUnits

```
Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object {$_.AccountSkuId -eq "Company365:EXCHANGESTANDARD" } | ft -AutoSize

AccountSkuId                   ActiveUnits WarningUnits ConsumedUnits
------------                   ----------- ------------ -------------
Company365:EXCHANGESTANDARD    274         0            274
```

How would I now set about comparing the column ActiveUnits to ConsumedUnits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `Format-Table` statement. `Format-*` statements are for displaying data, so they shouldn't be used when further processing is required.

If you want to filter for items where `ActiveUnits` is greater than `ConsumedUnits` you could add the check to the `Where-Object` condition:

```psh
Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object {
  $_.AccountSkuId -eq "Company365:EXCHANGESTANDARD" -and
  $_.ActiveUnits -gt $_.ConsumedUnits
} | ...
```

If you need to take action based on whether `ActiveUnits` is or isn't greater than `ConsumedUnits` you'd use a conditional in a loop:

```psh
Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object {
  $_.AccountSkuId -eq "Company365:EXCHANGESTANDARD"
} | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.ActiveUnits -gt $_.ConsumedUnits) {
    # do some
  } else {
    # do other
  }
} | ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This should help with the next steps!